# Dump hadoop configuration in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I use `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set` to set configuration.
How do I dump those config?Either print them on console or dump them to file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump hadoop configurations to xml file (I am assuming you are using Scala)

```
    val out = new FileOutputStream("conf.xml")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.writeXml(out)
```